# Reduction formulae

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

$$I_{n}=\int x^n(1-x^2)^{\frac{1}{2}} dx$$
Show that 
$$(n+2)I_{n}=(n-1)I_{n-2}-x^{n-1}(1-x^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}$$

I can't seem to get this answer. Can someone please explain how to get to this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Break the first $x^n$ up so you may use u-substitution.

Comment: How do you mean?

Answer (score 3):

Rewrite $I_n$ in this way:
$$ I_n = -\frac{1}{3}\int x^{n-1} \frac{3}{2}(1-x^2)^\frac{1}{2} (-2x) \, dx$$

and note that derivative of $(1-x^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}$ is $\frac{3}{2}(1-x^2)^\frac{1}{2} (-2x)$.

Then integrate by parts and rearrange.